# Replace RFID with external pilot

Tags: rfid

im my company there is a gate, which can be open with standard RFID card like this [image]

is there any why to replace it with external pilot ? How to do it ?

EDIT:
How do I understand it: when I close my card to the gate, card emits some magnetic field. Is that possibile to measure parameters of that wave, and build the pilot which would send the same wave to the gate but from extendet (2 meters) distance ?

Comment: Could you be more specific what you mean by "external pilot"?

Comment: @Stefan edited.

Comment: I think we're getting lost in translation here. A 'pilot' is the guy who flys a plane. You seem to be looking for a long-range RFID tag/transponder. Try googling 'active rfid tag' since the card you have there is a 'passive rfid tag'.

Answer (score 1):

You need to research about how RFID works.

The RFID reader emits a radio wave. The wire loop antenna in your photo picks up enough power (when close to the transmitter) to power the chip which is also visible in your photo.

The chip modifies the radio signal in a way that the transmitter can sense and encodes the ID back to the reader as a binary data stream.

I see your edit now but 'pilot' is not the correct word.

I think the answer to your question is 'no'. The RFID card is not a normal 'transmitter' but modifies the signal from the reader.

Comment: Some RFID readers can 'tell' between active & passive RFID chips either by timing, or by varying the output signal. Due to this, you _might_ be able to "fool the system" using an active device, but if it's a good security system, you might just end up triggering alarms & having a rather embarassing "question-and-answer" session with security. :-o